# How to get child window url from parent window using javascript/ type script

Tags: javascript, angular

I use `window.open()` to open third party url in  child window (pupop window). Now i want to identify the url of child window change or not in parent window code.  How can i do it please help me.

```
let childUrl = "https://www.goami.co";

console.log(childUrl, "childUrl=")

this.windowRef = window.open(childUrl, "child", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=430,height=220,left=500,top=100");

this.windowRef.postMessage("message", "targetOrigin", false);

window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    if (event.origin == "https://www.goami.com")
        console.log(event.origin, "childUrl=")
    return;

}, false);
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @alfian5229  please check my code

"https://www.goami.co" this url after some time redirect to https://www.goami.com. this url